# Select option2 value from database after first option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following form:

```
 <form action="" method="post" target="_self">
             <div id="qcategory_1">Product</div>
             <div id="qcategory">
               <select name="Category" class="dropmenu" id="Category">
                 <option value="">Any</option>
                 <option value="Keyboard"<?php if ($_POST['Category']=="Keyboard") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Keyboard</option>
                 <option value="Piano"<?php if ($_POST['Category']=="Piano") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Piano</option>
               </select>
             </div>
             <div id="qbrand_1">Brand</div>
             <div id="qbrand">
               <select name="Manufacturer" class="dropmenu">
               <option>Any</option>
              <script type="text/javascript">   $("#Category").change(function() {
    $("#Manufacturer").load("Menubackend.php?choice=" + $("#Category").val());
});</script>
               </select></form>
```

The backend fill is as follows:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/dconn.php'); ?>
<?php
$Category=$_POST['Category'];


    $choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['choice']);

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer FROM products WHERE Category LIKE '$choice'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row{'products'} . "</option>";
    }




?>
```

I am trying to display the Manufacturers as a option value for the second drop down menu based on the first one, however this doesn't seem to retrieve any value from the db at all.
Any suggestion welcome

Comment: what does `echo $choice;` print?

Comment: That seems to be empty, that might be the problem. I'll try and chase it

Comment: try `$_GET['choice'];` instead..

Comment: anyway i can't see any submitted form here, so i wonder how you would get the values then

Comment: You select the category based on $_POST('choice'] which isn't in the form but is passed in the query string generated by some jquery. But you also check the value of $_POST('Category'] which won't be passed through unless you submit the form (which I don't think the jquery is doing).

Comment: Ok I have change the following : <select name="Category" class="dropmenu" id="Category"onchange="this.form.submit()"> and in the backend:$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer FROM products WHERE Category LIKE '$Category'"; However it still does not select the Manufacturers. When checking $_POST['Category'] it prints out the correct value.

Comment: Have you changed it to use $_POST['Category'] instead of $_POST['choice'] to assign a value to $choice?

Comment: Changed it like this: $choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Category']);
 
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer FROM products WHERE Category LIKE '$choice'";

Comment: Echo out $query and see what the SQL is that it is trying to execute.